# How to pass a parameter in a Marshmallow schema

Tags: flask-restful, marshmallow

Using Python, Flask and marshmallow, if I have a schema:

```
class ParentSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Int(dump_only=True)
    children = fields.Nested('ChildSchema', dump_only=True)
```

and a class `Parent` which has a method:

```
class Parent():
    getChildren(self, params):
        pass
```

How do I get Marshmallow to pass the necessary parameters to `Parent.getChildren` when serialising the object and then populate `ParentSchema.children` with the results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the solution is to add a `get_attribute` method to the schema class and to assign the parameters to the `context` attribute of the `ParentSchema` class. This alters the default behaviour that Marshmallow uses to extract class attributes when building the schema.

```
class ParentSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Int(dump_only=True)
    children = fields.Nested('ChildSchema', dump_only=True)

    def get_attribute(self, key, obj, default):
        if key == 'children':
            return obj.getChildren(self.context['params'])
        else:
            return getattr(obj, key, default)
```